# Projection onto empirical manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, constrained-dynamics

I want to define the dynamics of a system to follow a specific trajectory in the state space indicated by a point cloud/previous measurements/observations that lie on a manifold, given some initial and final points.

Let us consider a simple example:
In the following figure, i have noisy measurements from an oscillating system. I want my system to follow a trajectory to start from one green circle and end at the second green circle BUT will obey the curvature indicated by the empirical manifold the red points.

[image: point cloud of observations]

The system will follow some baseline simple dynamics (indicated here by the orange line) that ensures that the second point will be reached, and at every timestep I'd like to add some penalty cost that will drive the system towards the lower dimensional manifold indicated by the red points.

So I would like to be able to set some cost that maximizes the projection of the trajectory on the said empirical manifold.

My problem is that most manifold learning methods, identify a lower dimensional manifold, but they only return lower dimensional co-ordinates of the point cloud to a lower dimensional space. Here, I would need either the geodesic of the learnt manifold so I can constrain my trajectory to follow the geodesic, or at least some mapping that would transform a random point of the ambient space to the lower dimensional space.

Has anyone seen any method or publication that performs what I describe here?
or does anyone has any indication of what to read and how to proceed onward?

Answer (score 2):

Nonlinear principal component analysis produces both a projection mapping to the reduced manifold, and a recovery map. The basic paper is

M.A. Kramer, Nonlinear Principal Component Analysis Using Autoassociative Neural Networks, 1991.

See also

M. Scholz et al., Non-linear PCA: a missing data approach, 2005.

Since your manifold is circular, you may need to use [circular neural networks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.192.6341&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

The method is not without drawbacks, see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3302424_Limitations_of_nonlinear_PCA_as_performed_with_generic_neural_networks) and [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-9119-3_8).

Comment: Thank you. This is just an example with circular manifold, I would like to find a approach that would work for arbitrary manifolds. I will look at your suggestions